# popover issue with Firefox when svg has position:absolute

Tags: firefox, svg, popover, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a popover that works perfectly fine with Safari, Chrome and IE but doesn't work in Firefox, (it doesn't appear).

I have created a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/sregorcinimod/7x4vuwLr/8/

When you click on the blue rectangle a popover should appear.

The problem line is the fact that i have a position:absolute on the svg

```
#spacing svg{
  max-width:100%;
  position:absolute; //this is the line that is causing issues
  bottom:0px;
}
```

If I remove that line the popover appears but I need that in for other things.

The constraints are:

1. I need to have position:absolute on the svg due to other more complex things that aren't in the jsfiddle i.e. responsive positioning of multiple layered svgs.
2. I need the trigger to be focus and not click because I need the popover to be dismissed when the user either clicks on the x in the title or anywhere in the browser window.

Things I have tried:

1. wrapping the svg in a div.
2. changing the container.

Comment: @RobertLongson - when you click on the blue rectangle a popover appears. Works fine for me on Safari 10.0.3, IE 11.0.096..., and Chrome 57.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a tabindex attribute to the rect e.g. tabindex="0"

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you I would never have thought of that. Just tried it on the big 4 browsers and it works